# Javascript objects & loops

Tags: javascript, loops

Sorry for the broad question title.

I'm building an app in Titanium and I'm currently integrating google maps with annotations - I'm grabbing the data from my API but I have hit a brick wall trying to make this easy for my self.

For a foreword, the map module I use allows me to do the following:

```
mapView.addAnnotations([anno1,anno2,anno3]);
```

and

```
mapView.removeAnnotations([anno1,anno2,anno3]);
```

I would like to create a function that allows me to add the annotiations and remove them upon an user requested update of the map annotations.

I'm currently at a point where I have this:

```
var annotations = {};

for(c = 0; c <= countedOffers; c++ ) {
    var offerName = offers[c]['offer_name'];
    var offerCat = offers[c]['offer_cat_id'];
    var offerlong = offers[c]['offer_long'];
    var offerlat = offers[c]['offer_lat']

    var anno = 'offer'+c;

    if(anno in annotations == false) {
        annotations['anno'+c] = {'name':offerName, 'offercat': offerCat, 'offerlng':offerlong, 'offerlat':offerlat};
    }
    if(countedOffers - c == 1) {
        loopThrough(annotations);
    }
}
```

I can add the above annotiations by doing something like this:

```
var annotation = maps.createAnnotation({
lat:,
lng:,
etc...
});
mapView.addAnnotation(annotation);

function loopThrough(obj){
    for(var key in obj){
        if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
        if(typeof obj[key] !== 'object'){
            Ti.API.error(obj[key]);
        } else {
            loopThrough(obj[key]);
        }
    }
}
```

The Ti.API.error gives me something like this:

```
joshes big burger house
1
-1.2577
51.7520
joshes big burger house
3
-1.2577
51.7520
jj offer
1
-1.2577
51.7520
No Photo
1
-1.2577
51.7520
joshes web offer
2
-1.2577
51.7520
Joshes Web Offer
3
-1.2577
51.7520
```

Which is fine, but I would like them to be inside of a variable or something I can loop through. I will always know how many I need to add and remove.

```
mapView.addAnnotations([anno1,anno2,anno3]);
mapView.removeAnnotations([anno1,anno2,anno3]);
```

I was thinking I could implode (or something similar) and get the object keys and put them in the above add/remove annotations

Sorry if anything is unclear, I'll update my question if needed.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://lodash.com/docs#toArray

Answer (score 0):

Lol, I was approaching this situation in a silly way - it was an easier solution to just push easy item in my object in to an array.